# Syntax to pass an array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

I have a "v" array that I want to pass to a function. Are "v" and "&v" equivalent or is there any difference between them?

For example:

```
char v[4]
scanf("%s", v);

scanf("%s", &v);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v`, `&v`, `&v[0]` differ by type but by value they're the same.

- `v` is of type `char[4]`; array of 4 `char`s
- `&v` is of type `char (*) [4]`; pointer to an array of 4 `char`s
- `&v[0]` is of type `char*`; pointer to a `char`

Answer (score 2):

`v` is address of `v[0]` and `&v` is address of whole array. Fortunately both will have same value. But any arithmetic on these pointers will access differently. For example

`(v+1)` and `(&v + 1)` are not same.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` expects the argument corresponding to `%s` to have type `char *`; the expression `&v` will have type `char (*)[4]`.  Even though the *values* will be the same, the types will be different, and type matters.

*For this case*, you want to call it as

```
scanf("%s", v);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always ask to the compiler itself...:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char v[4];

    printf ("   v         &v      &v[0]\n");
    printf ("%p  %p  %p\n", v, &v, &v[0]);
    printf ("%p  %p  %p\n", v+1, &v+1, &v[0]+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Using MinGW2.95 , this prints the following:

```
   v         &v      &v[0]
0240FF24  0240FF24  0240FF24
0240FF25  0240FF28  0240FF25
```

As you see, the three expressions yield the same value for the base array address, so they can be used with `scanf()` (although I agree that the correct expression for `scanf()` is the first one). If you want to perform some arithmetic pointer on these, they have not the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes If you want to know base address of array then you can just write v i.e. It will give

address of first element in array.and &v will give address of complete array.

`v[0]` is same as `(v+0)`, `v[1]` is same as `(v+1)` and so on.

hope you get it.